# VLC - Stream that can be played by html img

Tags: streaming, vlc, codec, ip-camera

I have set a ip camera security system in my house using a Cubieboard running Lubuntu 12.04, and some of my cameras are getting poor wifi signal. This way, since I have a constant stream from the camera to the Cubieboard, whe I try to access the camera remotelly the connection gets really bad.

The sollution I came up is having the Cubieboard to receive a stream from the camera and, using VLC, I re-stream it. This way the recording system that runs on the Cubie itself get a strem from VLC and the remote access from wherever I am gets tht VLC stream also, not overloading the wifi connection between the camera and the router.

I get this stream by using the following command:

```
http://user:password@camIp:camPort/videostream.cgi
```

This gives me a MJPEG stream that I re-stream like this:

```
cvlc http://user:password@camIp:camPort/videostream.cgi --sout "#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8888}"
```

Now I want to use a html to display all my cameras in kiosk mode using some browser. Below is the simple code I've written.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body
        {
            cursor:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:gray; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
        <img src="http://user:password@camIp:camPort/videostream.cgi" style="width:100%; height:100%"/>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color:gray; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
        <img src="http://cubieIp:8888" style="width:100%; height:100%"/>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color:gray; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
    </div>

    <div style="background-color:gray; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The stream I get directly from the camera is being displayed in my page, but not the one I get from the Cubieboard. I guess that must have to do with the container or codec, but as I'm not very familiar with this, I don't know how to identify the container used by the camera in order to try to use the same one on VLC. It would be nice if I could find a way to do it without having to transcode the stream, in order to save the cubie's limited processing power.

Any help will be very much appreciated!